# action bar does not show After applying theme

Tags: android

This my style page:

```
<resources>
<color name="for_custom">#ff4db0e8</color>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/for_custom</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTheme">@color/for_custom</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">homeAsUp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And this is my manifest:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

action bar does not show After applying theme.Why?
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on Lollypop+ the default Theme is Material, which does not show the ActionBar. This is because the [Material Design spec](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) remarks the [Toolbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) view as the new way to keep the buttons. If you want the old style, use `Theme.Holo.Light` instead of just `Theme.Light`